# $_GET undefined index

Tags: php, javascript

By passing a js variable to php code it displays a value at the end of the program.

But the problem is no mather what i try to initialise it with the score disapears at the end.

If i leave it alone everything displays as it should, but with the annoying undefined message until the last screen (where the value actually gets displayed).

```
$varOne = $xml->addChild('one', $_GET['resultone']);
```

The variable in the js is being past by using `window.location.href`

I have tried several isset ways but none of them seem to have succeeded in resolving this annoying problem.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried testing for $_GET and $_GET['resultone']?

```
if( isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['resultone']) ) {
}
```

Comment: I use to do `(isset($_GET['resultone']) && !empty($_GET['resultone']))`. $_GET is always set, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

The $_GET function reads the query string.  So your javascript code should look something like this:

window.location.href="myscript.php?resultone=123"

Is that how you're doing it?

Comment: that's right ? "it's the right solution" : "it's how I'm doing it"